# Make times on the site in user's local time zone

Tags: discussion, timezone, users, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make recent activity “today” etc. buttons based on user’s time zone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone)

Times on comments, questions, answers, etc (on the tool tip) are expressed in UTC. This is annoying. Can we please have these in local time? This requires no different storage or change in how SO works, it's just a case of adding or subtracting up to 12 to the number.

Comment: Jeff, this is not an exactly duplicate of that. That is about the grouping of daily acivity. This is purely about the time displayed in tooltips.