# Is there a Time Zone setting?

Tags: support, timezone, preferences

All the times seem to be in GMT. Is there a time zone setting so they will show up in my time zone?

Also will this affect the "consecutive day" badge calculations?

Comment: It's been requested and declined: [Make recent activity “today” etc. buttons based on user's time zone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone), [Make times on the site in user's local time zone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/make-times-on-the-site-in-users-local-time-zone); see also [When does a day start?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start) and [What Time Zone do the SO servers operate in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42179/) (and dozens of others)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the definiton of a "day" to be localized for users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users)

Comment: As for your second question, yes, this affects the "consecutive day" calculations. There are literally dozens of complaints about this on MSO, although most are from before the count was visible in user profiles and some have been deleted.

Comment: @Popular Demand: How can a time zone setting that does not exist affect the "consecutive day" calculations? Also, please move these comments and/or clarification to an answer so I can accept.

Comment: The reporting (and calculation) should be UTC, but a day in arrears.  The problem at the moment (_really obvious here in sunny **UTC+13** New Zealand_), is that the labels and reporting don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Is there a Chrome extension that can auto convert show (maybe as a pop up add-on to the UTC)  SE date-time stamps with local/ chosen time zones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My original comment:

> User-specific time zone settings have been requested and declined: [Make recent activity “today” etc. buttons based on user's time zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone), [Make times on the site in user's local time zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/make-times-on-the-site-in-users-local-time-zone); see also [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start) and [What Time Zone do the SO servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42179/) (and dozens of others)

Your comment makes no sense to me. There is a time zone setting: it's UTC for everyone. That's where the very definition of "day" for consecutive day calculations comes from, so how could it *not* affect the calculations?

Comment: "There is a time zone setting: it's UTC for everyone." ... Thanks, mod.

Comment: Well... it is. Although now that I read the comment again I see that what the OP actually said was slightly different than what he meant (whether it's configurable on a user-by-user basis). And for what it's worth, I wrote this answer two and a half years before I joined the team.

Comment: this is really annoying as far as consecutive days count is concerned... im pretty sure you can be on every day in your time zone but may have missed a UTC day by an hour or so, thus resetting your count. almost makes me think it is some dumb conspiracy to drive pageviews by making people try several times to get those dumb badges. no thanks i'm over it....

Comment: Is there a Chrome extension that can auto convert show (maybe as a pop up add-on to the UTC)  SE date-time stamps with local/ chosen time zones?

Comment: @user110857 what is the url of the setting pages, please?I fail to find out...

Comment: @Grace There's no configurable setting for time zone.

Comment: @Pops Please let us change our time zone. The current time-zone discrepancy is inconvenient and pretty annoying.

Answer (score 7):

I think a great deal of the issues that people with this could be addressed with some additional/better labels on the profile screens.

Maybe not right by the profile image/score, but maybe when you click on the Username to see profile, then click on Reputation, and see the graph.
Maybe an extra note here for emphasis, something like:

*"Note that profile 'days' for points go from midnight to midnight UTC (-a- to -b- your time)*"

with -a- and -b- coming from the client if possible?

Comment: Totally agree. at least let it be known on the profile page page that its UTC and not even close to your local time zone. I was on 67 consecutive visits before visiting at 8:30 pm and discovering my visit counter dropped back to 1. Learned the hard way......

Comment: @fontno - me too  ...  so you need to visit more than once a day to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this using the Stack App [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).

Among its [features](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features), there is the one requested here:

> - Convert timestamps to your local time
>
>   - Displays timestamps based on your time zone. You can also display time in 12-hour format by checking the option.