# April Fools should be UTC

Tags: feature-request, unicoins, april-fools, timezone

All of SE uses UTC. By relying on local time for rolling out <del>April Fools' jokes</del> exciting new features, they're already old news by the time those in western countries get a chance to see them.

I propose UTC be used for April Fools', rather than local time.

Very few sites use local time for such critical functionality. Why SE?

<sub>I realize I can change my time zone. That doesn't fundamentally solve the issue.</sub>

Comment: But then I wouldn't have stayed up until midnight last night.  Party pooper.

Comment: I don't know that I agree with the closure of this question. It's not *specifically* about the 2014 April Fools feature Unicoins. It's about SE's policy for April Fools on a year-over-year basis, and will be just as relevant again on March 31 2015

Answer (score 4):

As a Pacific-coaster, I feel your pain. The surprise is rather spoiled by Australians and their <strike>upside-down</strike> excessively-early timezone. (Australia [continues to annoy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/).) I found all about  Unicoins before I went to sleep last night and didn't see them until I woke.  That just tans my hide.

**However**, the point of April Fools is that it's flips the world upside down for a day. I imagine that people who enjoy the festivities early on this day have other problems to deal with the other 364 1/4 days of the year.  For instance:

- Being passed-out drunk when the ball drops in Times Square because the calendar flipped too early.
- Being constantly confused by co-workers saying that the day is Tuesday when it clearly it's Wednesday.
- Being asked by folks in my timezone: "What's the future like?"

Finally, they have one other disappointment:

- The joke ends before many people have started to enjoy it.

But to be honest, we can't win for losing:

[April Fool's Day changes should be based on the user's time zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44948/april-fools-day-changes-should-be-based-on-the-users-time-zone?rq=1)

**If you want to be surprised on April 1, don't read meta on March 31.**

Comment: Ah yes, "the future". I heard that joke waaaay too many times while living in Japan.

Comment: I'm from Australia. You insensitive *clod*.

Comment: @michaelb958: Truth be told, I lived in [Exmouth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exmouth,_Western_Australia) for two wonderful years. It's a wonderful country and you should be proud of it.