# Shouldn't consecutive days measure from midnight to midnight in the user's time zone?

Tags: feature-request, timezone, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the definiton of a “day” to be localized for users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users)

I've just discovered I missed a day in my "consecutive days" count, because I logged in yesterday morning, and logged in today in the evening.  Apparently, Stack Overflow runs on London time, so anyone logging in outside of London has the day boundary at a non-intuitive time.

Shouldn't the day-to-day tabulation be done relative to the user's timezone, not the server's?

Comment: You would think, wouldn't you.  But alas no... SOFU is all UTC.

Comment: FWIW, I saved my consecutive days count once by taking advantage of the UTC accounting.  I was going to be busy all day Saturday, so I logged in Friday night after 6 PM and next in early Sunday afternoon.