# Consecutive days visited by user would be better based on timezone of user

Tags: feature-request, preferences, consecutive-days, midnight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the definiton of a “day” to be localized for users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users)

It would be nice if the midnight point to start a new day were synced to the user's timezone instead of using the server's timezone.  Otherwise it can incorrectly report a broken streak of consecutive visits when the user visits in the morning yesterday and in the afternoon today but the server sees two days elapsed.  User could set their timezone as a preference for their user id.

Comment: [Dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406/shouldnt-consecutive-days-measure-from-midnight-to-midnight-in-the-users-time-z) of a [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users).