# Consecutive Day count reset this morning

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, consecutive-days

I have read a lot of the posts on here about consecutive days and how they are calculated, but I am not sure that I can explain this one...which is disappointing since I have been trying to get the consecutive days badges.

I logged in last night (SO) at 8/13/2010 @ 730P EST and my consecutive days count was somewhere in the teens (maybe 20's I don't remember).  I answered a question, browsed around for a bit longer and then went away.  This morning (8/14/2010 @ 815A EST), my consecutive days count is back to 1 (still on SO).

What is the exact method to calculate these?  Can anyone look to ensure that my days really should have been reset?  Its pretty crazy to attempt to go for a badge if when I log in twice within 11 hours I have my days reset.  And, just as an aside, its not so much about the badge as I do enjoy the site without the 'reward', but still would be nice to know why this reset occurred.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure about the first time? Stack Overflow Standard Time rolls over at 8 PM EST, so if you actually visited after 8:00, this would count as two visits on the same day.

Comment: All you have to do is check SO compulsively and the badges are yours!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging in twice within 11 hours has nothing to do with logging in every day -- you could log in 400 times in 20 minutes, but if you then don't log in the next day, you're going to lose your consecutive day count.

Did you actually check your consecutive day count yesterday and see it at 20? You said you:

> logged in last night (SO) at 8/13/2010 @ 730P EST and ... answered a question

It looks like you're talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481078/is-request-servervariablesremote-addr-reliable-enough/3481479#3481479), which was posted at **8**:30 EST, a half hour into 14 Aug. I can't see when you logged in (but [diamond mods can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning/61025#61025)), but if it was within a half hour before posting that, it happened today, not yesterday

Comment: well, looks like my mind was still on CST from my trip this week according to mmyers below.  Eh, no biggie I suppose.  Just wish that a login on the 13th and a login on the 14th counted as consecutive days :/

Answer (score 6):

If I visit every day, that should count. No matter where I live.

It's up to Stack Overflow to get my timezone correct.

I have visited daily for the past months but due to timezone differences my consecutive day count gets reset during the weekends because that is when I visit at the end of the day and not in the morning.

**Edit:**

If I visit Friday morning and Saturday evening that should still count as daily.
Even though it's more than 24 hours apart.

Comment: as long as you visit once in every 24 hour period, you'll get it -- timezone isn't relevant

Comment: It should be. Please read my edit.

Comment: @Jeff - I think the Friday morning Saturday evening example is a great one to illustrate visiting on consecutive days, more than 24 hours apart, where local time zone matters.

Comment: This is in no way an answer to the original question; it's a feature request that's already been proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406/shouldnt-consecutive-days-measure-from-midnight-to-midnight-in-the-users-time-z), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13435/use-users-timezone-for-vote-limit-reputation-cap-badges-etc)

Comment: Doesn't even have to be Friday morning and Saturday evening, could be Friday evening at 9pm Pacific Time, then Saturday evening at 9:10pm. I could visit on consecutive "days" a few minutes late, and miss it because it wasn't within a 24 hour period like Jeff pointed out. Never made the UTC connection until now. The badge is actually "Visited the site each 24 hour period for 100 consecutive 24 hour periods."

Answer (score 2):

According to your login history:

> Tommy -> User accessed site 16 hours ago **(that's Saturday the 14th UTC, just barely)**
>   Tommy -> User accessed site 2 days ago **(on the 12th?)**
>   Tommy -> User accessed site Aug 11 at 1:10

It looks like you missed either the 12th or the 13th, UTC. Michael Mrozek's answer is the most likely explanation for how this could have happened.

Comment: well crap - thanks for looking.  Guess I got around to my machine around 730 but SO must have been a site or two down on the list of things to check before bed :)

Comment: Would you be able to check my login history? I have SO as my home page, and I open it every day at work - but it seems my counter reset to 3 days for this week despite browsing SO every day :(

Comment: @Codesleuth: It shows that you accessed the site around the same time every morning this week except Tuesday. There's nothing logged for Tuesday.

Comment: I'm willing to call this a bug - I definitely logged in and browsed around each day this week. Both at 9AM BST and 5PM BST usually to check for responses (when I get to work and then when I leave). I'll never get this badge at this rate :(