# Counter for consecutive visits was reset?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Day count reset this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning)

I was checking my account today and saw that the counter for consecutive visits was reset. I talked with a friend and he said that the same situation occured into his account. What is the reason for this problem and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is probably answered already: **[Why was the consecutive visit counter for my account reset?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning)**.

Comment: It is correct... But I can't login in Meta (something wrong with my StackExchange account), so if someone can move this question, I would appreciate

Comment: @RafaelVerger you visited this site two days after writing this, so assume your account is now all good?

Comment: yeah yeah... I was confused cause the time difference between my location and stackoverflow servers. -- @ShaDowWizArd